Ignore TailwindCSS height of a container in a container?
I want the job offers to land under the title, but the title itself is still centred by the height. Can anyone help me with this?
Here is a screenshot with:

And here is one without + a drawing of where it should go:

I have tried it with the following code
> <div class="flex 2xl:flex-row justify-start items-center w-full
> md:w-9/12 2xl:w-full 2xl:justify-center min-h-[38rem] h-[88vh]
> relative">
>     <div class="space-y-8 xl:ml-4 2xl:min-w-[52rem] 2xl:w-[62rem]" id="left">
>         <img class="w-6 xl:w-8 transition-all delay-100 ease-in-out" src="Vector.svg" alt="Fluxify Vector">
>         <div class="space-y-3">
>             <h2 class="font-syne font-medium text-[1.435rem] leading-[1.525rem] lg:text-[1.735rem] lg:leading-[1.825rem]
> 2xl:text-[1.835rem] 2xl:leading-[2.225rem] line-clamp-3
> 2xl:line-clamp-2 transition-all delay-100 ease-in-out">Deine Karriere
> bei uns - Bewerbe Dich noch heute!</h2>
>             <p class="font-sura text-md leading-4 md:text-lg 2xl:text-lg text-[#8A8A8A] md:leading-5 2xl:leading-5
> line-clamp-4">Bist du Softwareentwickler, Webseitenentwickler,
> Designer, Konzeptentwickler, Systemadministrator oder kannst du einen
> anderen Bereich der IT abdecken? Bewirb Dich bei uns - wir bieten Dir
> als Freelancer Kunden & Aufträge mit fairer Bezahlung.</p>
>             <div class="">
>                 <x-jobs.offers/>
>             </div>
>         </div>
>     </div>
>     <div class="2xl:flex justify-end w-full hidden" id="right">
>         <div class="select-none relative 2xl:left-44">
>             <img class="rounded-[1.56rem] min-w-[28.5rem] 2xl:max-w-[38rem]" src="placeholder-01.jpg">
>         </div>
>     </div> </div>


1. Remove height constraints:
-<div class="flex 2xl:flex-row justify-start items-center w-full md:w-9/12 2xl:w-full 2xl:justify-center min-h-[38rem] h-[88vh] relative">
+<div class="flex 2xl:flex-row justify-start items-center w-full md:w-9/12 2xl:w-full 2xl:justify-center relative">

2. Use flexbox for vertical alignment:
+<div class="flex 2xl:flex-row justify-start items-start w-full md:w-9/12 2xl:w-full 2xl:justify-center relative">

3. Adjust child container padding or margin for optimal space (Optional):
<div class="space-y-8 ...">


Nope, I want the height of the container for the image on the right to be 100vh and then the text on the left centred vertically through the image. The offers should be available below the text...

https://i.ibb.co/v4DmqGm/grafik.png - Here is what it looks like
